# Trello - Make url of trello card permanent

Tags: trello

We are using the URL of trello cards as branch names in our versioning tool (git) so that devs can easily find the card just by searching for the branch name.

However, if someone changes the title, then the URL also changes and the dev does not find the card with just the branch name.

Is there a way to make the URL permanent or at least make it so that a 301/302 redirect is created from the old to the new url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trello card urls are of the form:

`https://trello.com/c/<id>/<title>`

The `<id>` is the only required part of the url, and if the `<title>` part is removed, the url will still work and will redirect back to the form with the `<title>`.

So, for this card url:

https://trello.com/c/w1B6bZE0/18-add-new-notes-ideas-or-brainstorming-items-to-this-list

You could store the url as https://trello.com/c/w1B6bZE0/ and if you click on that link you'll see that it redirects back to the former regardless of the card's title.

Comment: Nice, this means we can use that ID instead of the whole URL atleast.